# Is it possible to apply Spring-animation on img src change using React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, react-spring

In my `react` application, I am trying to use `react-spring` to fade in an image when the `src` changes. I have multiple images in the `/img/` directory named to match the current `activeIndex` I want to display. Currently using below code, the fade in effect is only applied on the first image. What am I doing wrong?

```
import React from 'react';
import { Spring } from 'react-spring/renderprops';

export default function MyComponent(props) {

    const {
        activeIndex
    } = props;

    return (
        <div>
            <Image activeIndex={activeIndex}  />
        </div>
    )
}

function Image(props) {

    const {
        activeIndex
    } = props;

    return (
        <Spring
            from={{opacity: 0}}
            to={{opacity: 1}}
        >
            { props => (
                <div style={props}>
                    <div>
                        <img src={ `/img/${activeIndex}/01.jpg` } alt="" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}
        </Spring>
    )
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code that is using `MyComponent`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the fade in effect, make sure that every Image has different key. In this case react will repeat the initial effect.

```
return (
    <div>
        <Image key={activeIndex} activeIndex={activeIndex}  />
    </div>
)
```

If you want a fade out effect as well. I would try the Transition component instead of the Spring component.